# JSON Schema with array of different object types with mandatory property fails to validate

Tags: json, jsonschema

I edited the original schema to show my real problem

i am having this JSON schema

```
 {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "stages": {
          "type": "array",
          "minItems": 1,
          "items": {
            "anyOf": [
              {"$ref": "clone.json#/clone"},
              {"$ref": "clone.json#/build"}
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

With Ref schema (clone.json) as:

```
{    
    "proper": {
        "type": "object",
        "additionalProperties": false,
        "properties": {
                      "name1": {"type": "string"},
                      "name2": {"type": "string"}
                    },
                    "required": ["name2"]
    },
    "clone": {
        "type": "object",
        "additionalProperties": false,
        "properties": {
            "clone": {
                "anyOf": [
                    {
                        "$ref": "#/proper"
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "object",
                        "additionalProperties": false,
                        "properties": {
                            "cloneName": {
                                "description": "The repo name",
                                "type": "string"
                            }
                        },
                        "required": [
                          "cloneName"
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    },
    "build": {
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
            "build": {
                "anyOf": [
                    {
                        "$ref": "#/proper"
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "object",
                        "additionalProperties": false,
                        "properties": {
                            "buildName": {
                                "description": "The repo name",
                                "type": "string"
                            }
                        },
                        "required": [
                          "buildName"
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

BTW:In my real schema i am getting the "properties" section from a different schema as $ref

and as test Json i am using

```
{
     "stages": [
          {
                "clone": {}
          },
          {
                "build": {}
          }
     ]
}
```

and (at least in vscode) i am not getting any worning for missing required parameter

can you please help me understand what am I doing wrong?
thanks

Answer (score 0):

The first issue is your root schema has `stages` defined but you are not constraining the schema to `additionalProperties: false`. This is not a requirement, but if you pass any other property name at the root, it does not consider any validation constraints. As in your example instance, your root element is `test2` and not `stages`, so no validation is applied against your data instance.

This will fix the first issue.

```json
{
    "stages": [
        {
            "test": {}
        }
    ]
}
```

Secondly, your `anyOf` subschemas are unconstrained for additional properties. This means your second `anyOf` subschema passes validation of `test: {}` because you have no constraints on `test` in the second subschema. One way you can constrain these type of schemas is to use `additionalProperties: false` in each subschema; then you will see the error for missing `required`

```json
             "items": {
                "anyOf": [
                    {
                        "type": "object",
                        "additionalProperties": false,  <--- HERE
                        "properties": {
                            "test": {
                                "type": "object",
                                "properties": {
                                    "name1": {
                                        "type": "string"
                                    },
                                    "name2": {
                                        "type": "string"
                                    }
                                },
                                "required": [
                                    "name2"
                                ]
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "object",
                        "additionalProperties": false,  <---HERE
                        "properties": {
                            "test1": {
                                "type": "object",
                                "properties": {
                                    "name1": {
                                        "type": "string"
                                    },
                                    "name2": {
                                        "type": "string"
                                    }
                                },
                                "required": [
                                    "name1"
                                ]
                            }
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
```

Comment: Thank you @jeremy-fiel for your detailed answer, for the first hulf it was my mistake since i used a more general schema to test it.
for the second it is indeed worked, but when i am using the same as $ref i still get the same problem.
I will edit the question so the real problem will be there.

Comment: your schema appears to be valid. I tried it with Ajv validator.  I don't think you can use VS Code with referenced schemas, that could be incorrect information though.  can you give the full example of how you are trying to use it in VSC?

Comment: Thank you again for checking my schema, I added also a new Json for testing my code, that what I use. what editor you suggest for using such schema?